# Auto update sluggable field with Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, slug

I'm using CodeIgniter with Doctrine in a project. One of my models has the [Sluggable behavior](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/behaviors/en#core-behaviors:sluggable). The slug is created according to another field **X** when the object is saved. I was wondering if there was a way to automatically update this slug field when the **X** field is updated.

At the moment, if I update the **X** field, the slug field remains with the sluggable format of the old **X** field value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never mind guys. Since I'd be using the slug field like a primary key, it'd be wiser if it wasn't modifiable.

Answer (score 2):

You can define "canUpdate" => true. So the slug gets updated every time you change the X field